# BindException Address already in use, but using reuse

Tags: java, sockets, networking

i have a problem, with my networking...

```
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        int nreq = 1;
        System.out.println("Hall000");
        try {
            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(6677);
            sock.setReuseAddress(true);
            sock.setSoTimeout(1000);
                Socket newsock = sock.accept();
                System.out.print("\n");
                System.out.println("Creating command...");
                System.out.print("\n");
                new answercall();

                nreq++;
                System.out.println(nreq);
                final DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(
                        ss.getInputStream());
                // Einlesen
                diny1 = (din).read();
                diny2 = (din).read();
                diny3 = (din).read();
                diny4 = (din).read();
                diny5 = (din).read();
                diny6 = (din).read();
                diny7 = (din).read();
                System.out.println("diny" + diny1 + " " + diny2 + " "
                        + diny3 + " " + diny4 + " " + diny5 + " " + diny6
                        + " " + diny7);
                setDiny1(diny1);
                setDiny2(diny2);
                setDiny3(diny3);
                setDiny4(diny4);
                setDiny5(diny5);
                setDiny6(diny6);
                setDiny7(diny7);
                System.out.println(diny1 + " " + diny2 + " " + diny3 + " "
                        + diny4 + " " + diny5 + " " + diny6 + " " + diny7
                        + " " + diny8);
                getSharedPreferences(DINY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putInt(DINY1, diny1).commit();
                getSharedPreferences(DINY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putInt(DINY2, diny2).commit();
                getSharedPreferences(DINY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putInt(DINY3, diny3).commit();
                getSharedPreferences(DINY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putInt(DINY4, diny4).commit();
                getSharedPreferences(DINY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putInt(DINY5, diny5).commit();
                getSharedPreferences(DINY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putInt(DINY6, diny6).commit();
                getSharedPreferences(DINY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putInt(DINY7, diny7).commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IO error" + e);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

LogCat tells me that:

IO errorjava.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

I know what it means, but i dont know, why it comes... im using reuse, so it shouldnt come, should it? what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html):

> The behaviour when SO_REUSEADDR is enabled or disabled after a socket is bound (See isBound()) is not defined.

You have to create the socket without binding, set `SO_REUSEADDR` and bind afterwards:

```
ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket();
sock.setReuseAddress(true);
sock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(6677));
```

PS: You minimize the amount of people willing to help you, when trying to prevent them from improving your question.

Comment: @MinakoAino Your reputation is not reduced when someone edits your question.  It is only reduced if someone downvotes the question.  Being careless with your grammar and punctuation then being aggressive towards anyone who tries to make your question easier to understand may encourage people to downvote you.

Comment: maybe youre right.... i was just a little angered about that... someone made my sentence to a complete other meaning, than i wanted it... btw, could you pls explain, what is meant with sO_REUSEADDR? i still get my exception

Comment: The SO_REUSEADDR section in the [socket man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) gives a good explanation.  You can use this option to bind to an address that was recently closed but cannot forcibly bind to an address that already has an active listening socket.  Do you have another instance of your server already running?

Comment: pls wait a moment, ill check this... i am sure, i am not running another instance, but who knows... if i am running another instance unknown, would it help just to change the port?

Comment: checked... not even one else instance running. This i get when i start my app: IO errorjava.net.SocketTimeoutException then, at the second connectingtry i get my adresse in use Exception..

Comment: The `SocketTimeoutException` is caused by `#accept()` which only waits for the timeout you have set (i.e. one second).

Comment: but its neccessary, isnt it?

Comment: @MinakoAino It's necessary if *you* need it. Only you know that. Why do you think you need a one second timeout on accept()?